# Suggestions on how to handle the integral $\int_0^R \frac{r^2(z-r\cos \theta)dr}{(r^2+z^2-2rz\cos\theta)^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I'm redoing some electromagnetism problems and came across this integral for a radial component. I already solved the problem in other ways, but I would like to know how to deal with this integral specifically:

> \begin{equation} \int_0^R \frac{r^2(z-r\cos (\theta))}{(r^2+z^2-2rz\cos(\theta))^{3/2}}\mathrm{d}r\end{equation}

I apologize if it's too simple.

Answer (score 5):

This is a trig sub problem, but you have to complete the square in the denominator. Rewriting the quadratic in the denominator:
$$r^2+z^2-2rz\cos(\theta)=(r-z\cos(\theta))^2-z^2\cos^2(\theta)+z^2,$$
we can perform the substitution $u=\arctan\left(\frac{r-z\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{z^2(1-\cos^2(\theta))}}\right)$ (draw an appropriate triangle to see where this comes from) to obtain an integral which is more elementary. From here, it's algebra soup, but there's nothing too complicated going on, aside from some standard trig integrals. I don't recommend finishing this by hand if you don't have to, but if you do, you should relabel your constants to make the expression easier to write.

Then we get an antiderivative, after which I will leave the pleasure of plugging in the bounds to you$\colon$
$$
\left[z \cdot\left(3 \sin ^2(\theta)-2\right) \ln \left(\left|\sqrt{r^2-2 z \cos (\theta) r+z^2}+r-z \cos (\theta)\right|\right)
+
\frac{z \cdot(2 \cos (\theta)-1)(2 \cos (\theta)+1) r-z^2 \cos (\theta)(2 \cos (\theta)-1)(2 \cos (\theta)+1)}{\sqrt{r^2-2 z \cos (\theta) r+z^2}}
-
\frac{z \sqrt{1-\cos (\theta)} \cos (\theta) \sqrt{\cos (\theta)+1}\left(r^2-2 z \cos (\theta) r+4 z^2 \sin ^2(\theta)\right)}{|z||\sin (\theta)| \sqrt{r^2-2 z \cos (\theta) r+z^2}}\right]_0^R
$$

Answer (score 2):

Denote $c := \cos \theta$ and $s := \sin \theta$, so that our integral is
$$\int_0^R \frac{r^2 (z - r c) \,dr}{(r^2 - 2 c z r + z^2)^{3 / 2}}$$
Completing the square in the denominator gives
$$\int_0^R \frac{r^2 (z - r c) \,dr}{[(r - c z)^2 + s^2 z^2]^{3 / 2}},$$
which (provided that $s \neq 0$) suggests the substitution $$r - c z = s z \tan \phi, \qquad \,dr = sz \sec^2 \phi \,d\phi ,$$ which in turn gives an integral rational in $\sin t, \cos t$, which can thus be handled by standard techniques. In any case the result is
$$\boxed{\left.z (1 - 3 c^2)\operatorname{arsinh} \left(\frac{r - c z}{z}\right)  + \frac{- c r^2 + (6 c^2 - 1) z r - 3 c z^2}{\sqrt{r^2 - 2 c z r + z^2}}\right\vert_{r = 0}^R}.$$

In the special case that $c = 0$, the (definite) integral simplifies to
$$z \operatorname{arsinh} \left(\frac{R}{z}\right) - \frac{z R}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}} .$$ All that remains is the special case $s = 0$, which implies that $c = \pm 1$ and then that the original integral is rational.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=r-z \cos t$, along with $a=z\sin t$, to express the integral as

\begin{align}
I=&  \int \frac{r^2(z-r\cos t)}{(r^2+z^2-2rz\cos t)^{3/2}}dr\\
=& \int \frac{-x^3\cos t +x^2 z(1-3\cos^2t)+x \cos t(3a^2-z^2)+z a^2\cos^2t}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx\\
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
& \int \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx
=\frac x{a^2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\\
 & \int \frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx
=-\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\\
 & \int \frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx
=-\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}+\sinh^{-1}\frac xa\\
 & \int \frac{x^3}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx
=\frac {x^2+2a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}
\end{align}
As a result
$$I= \frac{-x^2\cos t+x z(4\cos^2t-1)+\cos t(z^2-5a^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2\sin^2t}}\\
+z(1-3\cos^2t) \sinh^{-1}\frac x{a}
$$